# How to select group of items in a tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

In tensorflow.
How can I select all triplets, (`x, y, c`) where `c > 0.5`

[image]

I know this is probably a very basic question but I'm very new to Tensorflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `tf.where`. For example,

```
x = np.random.rand(20,3)
sess = tf.Session()
print x[tf.where(tf.greater(x[:,2], 0.5)).eval(session=sess)]
```

Or slightly cleaner,
`tf.boolean_mask(x,tf.greater(x[:,2], 0.5)).eval(session=sess)`

Comment: I had some difficulties with `tf.where` but `tf.boolean_mask` worked like a charm. Thanks :)